# Crystal Report 3of9 barcode not working on direct print

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fonts, crystal-reports

i'm developing a web application on VS2017 with Crystal Report, and i have implemented a report with barcode.

The font i have used is 3 of 9 Barcode, and i print the report directly with `PrintToPrinter()` method.
It works fine, but when i deploy the application on the server, and print the report, there is no barcode, but a string like `*123466*`.
I have also installed the font on the server "`3 of 9 Barcode.TTF`", but it displays me something like this `DA>>=A<D`.

And if i save the report on the disk, instead of printing it directly, the barcode is correct.

the same thing happens if i use `AbriBarcode39`, `AbriBarcode39a` etc...

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'm work with cristal on a desktop application. windows forms.

Try to instal this font: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aix8ovYm4JTXjdUje6CT5V6oO85Pcg
on the server.

I hope thats work for you!

More code bar fonts: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aix8ovYm4JTXjdUx5ewa4S3K_l2ArQ
Im my applications I use to install all of them.